# monitor Core utilization in Solaris Sparc

Tags: python, shell, scripting

I am trying to read the Sparc HW counter using the following command:

```
cpustat -c Instr_cnt .1
```

this command will be running forever (for some time until interrupted by user). Sample output is:

```
   time cpu event      pic1   
  1.011   0  tick      6450 
  1.011   1  tick      9681 
  1.011   2  tick      2015 
  1.012   3  tick       535 
  1.012   4  tick       615 
  1.012   5  tick      7513 
  1.012   6  tick       615 
  1.013   7  tick      5187 
  1.013   8  tick       615 
  1.013   9  tick       615 
  1.013  10  tick       615 
  1.014  11  tick     60077 
  1.014  12  tick       438 
  1.014  13  tick       615 
  1.014  14  tick       615 
  1.015  15  tick       615 
  1.015  16  tick       615 
  1.015  17  tick       438 
  1.016  18  tick       615 
  1.016  19  tick       615 
^C
```

Now I am trying to get every 4 cpu's in a core (each core has 4 cpus), add the number in pic1 and average them. Once the average reaches some threshold number, I want to do some load balancing.

I think the logic is: put all the elements from line 2 in an array, and then add every 4 of them. 
Looking for an output like:

```
**Core#      Average# of Inst   Utilization (#ofInst/cpu_cycle_perSec)**
   Core_0         xxxxxxxx            10%
   Core_1         xxxxxxxx            20%
    and so on....
```

I am novice in coding and if anyone could help me with some simple direction to do this, that would be great. This can be done in shell/python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: consider paring down your sample data. Does it really matter that you have X # of cores/CPUs. A solution for 1 core with 2 CPUs should give you the information you need. Also help us map your output 'Core_0' to the input. Assuming that the first line in your data is Core_0, it would be easier to help if you had 4 lines of sample data, and then a 5th line that was the 2nd iteration of Core_0 output. Or am I mis-guessing? Does your input list really match to your output? Does the `cpu` column just keep incrementing, or does it wrap back to 0? Less is more! Good luck !

Comment: Hello Shellter, 
I have a total of 32 cpus of which I am grouping different numbres at different times. Each core contains 4 cpus, thus I have a total of 8 cores. So Core0 has Cpu0,Cpu1,Cpu2,Cpu3; Core1 has Cpu4,Cpu5,Cpu6,Cpu7 and so on. 
the output of cpustat would go through all the cpus starting from 0 (if there is any activity in 0) all the way to 32 (or any other max number of Cpus in a group) and then start from 0 again and keep on going.